Why is this sufficient condition for $f$ is locally integrable?
Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$ be a measurable function and $I_k=[k,k+1)$ be a half open interval for each $k\in\mathbb Z$. Define $\mathcal I=\{I_k\}_{k\in\mathbb Z}\ $ and $\mathcal A:=\{A\in \sigma(\mathcal I)\mid f \ \text{is integrable on}\ A\ \}$, where $\sigma (\mathcal I)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal I.$
Then, I want to prove that $f$ is locally integrable if and only if $\mathbb R$ can be covered with countably many sets in $\mathcal A.$
I can see one direction ; if $f$ is locally integrable then $\mathbb R$ can be covered with countably many sets in $\mathcal A$, but I cannot prove the other direction.
Suppose $\mathbb R\subset \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ with $A_i\in\mathcal A$. Then I have to show for any compact set $K$, $\int_K |f|<\infty$. I don't know how I should use the condition $A_i\in\sigma(\mathcal I)$ and $\int_{A_i}|f|<\infty$ in order to show $\int_K|f|<\infty.$
For example, $$\int_K|f|=\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_K |f|=\int_{\cup_i A_i} \chi_K |f|\leqq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb R} \chi_{K\cap A_i}\ \ |f|\leqq
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb R} \chi_{A_i} |f|
$$ but this is not necessarily finite in spite of $\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_{A_i}|f|<\infty.$
Do you have any idea ?

Here are some facts that would be useful to construct the proof you're looking for:

Every compact subset of the real line is bounded, and therefore contained in some interval $[k,l)$ with $k, l$ integer.
If $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \subseteq A$, then $f$ is integrable over $B$.
And so, from Fact 2 and your covering hypothesis, for every integer $n$, $[n,n+1) \in \mathcal{A}$. (Why?)

So now your proof should work using a finite sum of integrals over the intervals $[k,k+1), [k+1,k+2), \dots, [l-1,l)$.

In the step3, is $n$ natural number instead of integer ?

Sorry @emoticon・ω・that was an error.

I cannot see the step3. (Maybe, I should use step2 as $B=[n,n+1)$ and then I could come to conclusion, but what should I use as $A$ ? If $[n,n+1)$ can be covered by finite union of $A_i's$, then I can use step2 as $A=$[the finite union of the $A_i's$]. But I cannot find the reason why $[n,n+1)$ can be covered by finite union of $A_i's.$)

@emoticon・ω・There is some $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $n+\frac{1}{2} \in A$ (this is by the covering hypothesis). The elements of $\sigma(\mathcal{I})$ are the unions of sets of the form $[k,k+1)$. Because $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{I})$ and $n + \frac{1}{2} \in A$ we have $[n,n+1) \subseteq A$. So by Fact 2, $[n,n+1) \in \mathcal{A}$.

O.K. Thanks for the answer.
